# jQuery - hidden class is not being displayed with fadeIn

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a hidden class `fadeThis`, which does not appear when I hover over the button.
Perhaps it is clashing with another class/div?

What I'm essentially trying to do is create a red fade in over the grey box, when the cursor hovers over the button, and then when the cursor leaves the box(not the button), I want it to return back to it's original state.

I've also added the CSS to help demonstrate

HTML

```
    <div class="imageOne">

        <div class="onClickThis"> <!-- hidden by default-->
            <h2 class="fadeThis">Whatever the text needs to be</h2> <!-- hidden by default-->
        </div>
        <div class="centerButton">
            <button class="btn">View More</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.imageOne{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.centerButton{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    padding-top:150px;
}

.btn{
    height: 30px;
    width:170px;

}

.onClickThis{
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: tomato;

}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onClickThis").hide();
    $(".fadeThis").hide();
    $(".btn").hover(function () {
        $(".imageOne").fadeIn("slow", function () {
            $(this).addClass("fadeThis onClickThis");
            $(".btn").remove();
        });
        $(".onClickThis").mouseleave(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("fadeThis onClickThis");

        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Why are there two closing divs in the end? You are aware of that?

Comment: You are removing `.btn` and again you try to add `mouseleave` event listener on the removed element?

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve] and add a complete snippet ([edit] and click `[<>]`) including relevant css.

Comment: .imageOne fadeIn - makes no sense as the `btn` view more is inside .imageOne so imageOne must already be visible.  Unless your provided html doesn't match your requirement, please ensure it does.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I will try out your suggestions and see how I go. I've also added some more details and code to help explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are looking for. Maybe you could provide more details.

Here is a demo started from your code with some changes added.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".onClickThis, .fadeThis").hide();
  
    $(".btn").hover(function () {
        $(".imageOne").fadeIn("slow", function () {
           $(".onClickThis, .fadeThis").fadeIn( 250 );
           $(".btn").fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="imageOne">
  <div class="onClickThis"> <!-- hidden by default-->
      <h2 class="fadeThis">Whatever the text needs to be</h2> <!-- hidden by default-->
  </div>
  <div class="centerButton">
      <button class="btn">View More</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```